# How Selenium WebDriver overcomes Same Origin Policy

Tags: webdriver

How Selenium WebDriver overcome same origin policy?

Same origin policy problem is in Selenium RC

Comment: Consider to clarify problem you are facing... Note that Selenium itself is not really governed by same-origin policy...

Comment: Hi I just wanted to know how selenium Webdriver overcomes the problem , means any new architecture model it has or what ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> First of all ***“Same Origin Policy”***  is introduced for security
>   reason, and it ensures that content of your site will never be
>   accessible by a script from another site.  As per the policy, any code
>   loaded within the browser can only operate within that website’s
>   domain.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                     ----------------------------------------------

### What it did???

> ***Same Origin policy*** prohibits JavaScript code from accessing elements from a domain that is different from where it was launched.
>   Example, the HTML code in www.google.com uses a JavaScript program
>   **"testScript.js"**. The ***same origin policy*** will only allow **testScript.js** to access pages within **google.com** such as **google.com/mail, google.com/login,** or **google.com/signup**. However, it cannot access pages from different sites such as
>   **yahoo.com/search or fbk.com** because they belong to different domains.

This is the reason why prior to Selenium RC, testers needed to install local copies of both Selenium Core (a JavaScript program) and the web server containing the web application being tested so they would belong to the same domain. 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

### How it is avoided???

> To avoid ***“Same Origin Policy”*** proxy injection method is used, in
>   proxy injection mode the **Selenium Server** acts as a client
>   configured HTTP proxy , which sits between the browser and application
>   under test and then masks the **AUT** under a fictional URL

Selenium uses java script to drives tests on a browser; Selenium injects its own js to the response which is returned from aut. But there is a java script security restriction ***(same origin policy)*** which lets you modify html of page using js only if js also originates from the same domain as html. This security restriction is of utmost important but spoils the working of Selenium. This is where Selenium server comes to play an important role.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I did not understand "How it is avoided" part . can u please explain with some example .

Comment: In layman terms,  it simply means Selenium webserver sit between the browser eg firefox and application(which is under test) for eg www.google.com, and mask it under a fictional url - so that it can trick the browser of thinking that both originated from the same url. As a result allow user to perform automated task on Application.                               In other word, Selenium server act as an HTTP proxy to "trick" the browser into believing that Selenium Core and the web application being tested come from the same origin.

Comment: Hi Abhishek,I'm facing same issue,as per your comments,we should install selenium standalone server jar file in WebServer ,where domain is present?

Answer (score 3):

Before Selenium WebDriver, Selenium was "Javascript Task Runner". It would set itself up as a server (locally), and open a browser pointed to the Selenium server running locally. So the browser is now talking to the Selenium Server running locally.

This is a problem though, because the browser is getting a script from Selenium which tells it that it wants to fetch resources from `http://websitetotest.com`. But the browser got this script from `http://127.0.0.1:9000/selenium` (for example). The browser says "hey this script came from local host and now it's requesting a resource from some outside website. This violated the **same-origin-policy**.

WebDriver came along and created a proxy to trick the browser into thinking that it is talking to the same server where both Selenium and the `websitetotest` are "located". Abhishek provided a concise explanation on this.

Comment: Hi Raphi,If you understood properly,can you please provide proper steps to overcome this issue,instead of paragraphs explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a late reply but, if you are referring to selenium webdriver and not selenium RC then the answer is you dont have to worry about same origin policy in case of webdriver since each browser has its own webdriver.This  is the whole advantage of webdriver as opposed to RC i.e no selenium core injection into the browser and no middleware client server between the browser and AUT.Webdriver provides a native OS level support in controlling the browser automation.